# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TestSproc

as
select COUNT(*) from dbo.TestCase
```

It doesn't make any useful things but I cannot invoke it via hibernate

```
Query query = m_entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL TestSproc()");
query.getSingleResult();
```

it causes java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'. other procedures has the same problem.

and there is no `TOP` statement in this procedures. Has anyone any ideas how it could be fixed?

Comment: It might be because you use `getSingleResult()`

Comment: Thanks, it really caused by getSingleResult()

Comment: If you're DB is Oracle, "Top" won't work. You use RowNum. So if you want the top 1, it's RowNum =1. 

If you want Top 10, it's RowNum <11.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you might want to try executing the sproc with `exec TestSproc` instead of `CALL TestSproc()`.  I would guess the `TOP` error is from `getSingleResult()`.  Fix the sproc error first.

Comment: If I use exec I get  java.sql.SQLException: Unrecognized SQL escape 'exec' at line position 6

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180759/call-oracle-stored-procedure-using-createnativequery